# Doing latest non zero lag in hivql

Tags: sql, hiveql

How to find the last non zero lag in a time series dataset using Hiveql?

I use below HiveQL to generate 20 lagges in a spark dataframe, but I need the latest non zero one, not simply the previous lag

```
for (int c = 1; c <= modelParameter.number_of_lags; c++) {              
    query.append(", lag(`" + col + "`," + c + ") OVER (ORDER BY ts" + i
            + ") as lagged_" + c + "_I_N_P_U_T_" + trimmedCol);
```

for example, if I have below data

```
ts,l,lagged_1_L
1,1,0
3,0,1
4,2,0
6,7,2
```

but I expect

```
ts,l,lagged_L
1,1,0
3,0,1
4,2,1
6,7,2
```

Comment: please show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I editted the question